# Data fetching issue from excel sheet to selenium web driver using core java

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have written a script (using core java) to fetch data from excel sheet (using apache poi) and store it into table provided in web application.
But problem is after fetching some values and inserting into table, script stops working, neither it fetches the value from excel nor it proceeds to next cell in table provided in web application.
My browser too working fine, idont have any browser hanging issue.
I am not able to find out problem which is halting my script.
is there any maximum limit to fetch data from excel sheet ?

Comment: Please add whatever core java code you have written to achieve above task. How is your excel formatted? Does it have any blank cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was facing screen size issue because of screen size it was halting the control so i used following commands to set browser window size and now it is working,

```
Dimension dim = new Dimension(3000,5000);
d.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

@mk08 Thank you for considering my problem.